No static method NavigationSuiteScaffoldLayout
I'm trying to implement NavigationSuiteScaffoldLayout for a Jetpack Compose project but unsure of how to resolve the error returned.

No static method NavigationSuiteScaffoldLayout

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Favorite
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationRail
import androidx.compose.material3.NavigationRailItem
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.adaptive.currentWindowAdaptiveInfo
import androidx.compose.material3.adaptive.navigationsuite.ExperimentalMaterial3AdaptiveNavigationSuiteApi
import androidx.compose.material3.adaptive.navigationsuite.NavigationSuite
import androidx.compose.material3.adaptive.navigationsuite.NavigationSuiteScaffoldDefaults.calculateFromAdaptiveInfo
import androidx.compose.material3.adaptive.navigationsuite.NavigationSuiteScaffoldLayout
import androidx.compose.material3.adaptive.navigationsuite.NavigationSuiteType
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableIntStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.demonavigationsuite.ui.theme.DemoNavigationSuiteTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3AdaptiveNavigationSuiteApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            DemoNavigationSuiteTheme {
                var selectedItem by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
                val navItems = listOf("Songs", "Artists", "Playlists")
                val navSuiteType = calculateFromAdaptiveInfo(currentWindowAdaptiveInfo())

                NavigationSuiteScaffoldLayout(
                    navigationSuite = {
                        if (navSuiteType == NavigationSuiteType.NavigationRail) {
                            NavigationRail {
                                navItems.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                                    NavigationRailItem(
                                        icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = item) },
                                        label = { Text(item) },
                                        selected = selectedItem == index,
                                        onClick = { selectedItem = index }
                                    )
                                }
                                Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
                            }
                        } else {
                            NavigationSuite {
                                navItems.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
                                    item(
                                        icon = { Icon(Icons.Filled.Favorite, contentDescription = item) },
                                        label = { Text(item) },
                                        selected = selectedItem == index,
                                        onClick = { selectedItem = index }
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp),
                        text = "Current NavigationSuiteType: $navSuiteType"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

build.gradle.kts (:app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.demonavigationsuite"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.demonavigationsuite"
        minSdk = 30
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
    implementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.graphics)
    implementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling.preview)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3)
    implementation(libs.androidx.material3.adaptive.navigation.suite)
    implementation(libs.androidx.adaptive.android)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)
    androidTestImplementation(platform(libs.androidx.compose.bom))
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.junit4)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.tooling)
    debugImplementation(libs.androidx.ui.test.manifest)
}

libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.4.0"
kotlin = "1.9.23"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.7.0"
activityCompose = "1.9.0"
composeBom = "2024.05.00"
adaptiveAndroid = "1.0.0-alpha12"


[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
androidx-material3-adaptive-navigation-suite = { module = "androidx.compose.material3:material3-adaptive-navigation-suite-android", version = "1.0.0-alpha06" }
androidx-adaptive-android = { group = "androidx.compose.material3.adaptive", name = "adaptive-android", version.ref = "adaptiveAndroid" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }


You need to update the compose compiler version that you set in your app gradle with composeOptions.kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion.
Which version to use is dependent on the version of other dependencies.
With the newest stable versions at the time of writing it could look like this:
kotlin = "1.9.23" // when you use ksp you need to update that too to match
composeCompiler = "1.5.13" // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler
composeBom = "2024.05.00" // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping
composeMaterial3Adaptive = "1.0.0-alpha12" // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#compose_material3_adaptive_version_10_2
composeMaterial3AdaptiveNavigationSuite = "1.0.0-alpha07" // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#compose_material3_adaptive_navigation_suite_version_10_2

If you cannot upgrade to the newest version for some of the dependencies you have to find out which older versions work together. For the alpha versions I haven't found a compatibility matrix so you might need to just try out older versions until you find one that works.

Please see the build.gradle.kts (:app) and libs.versions.toml files in my question

Yeah, that looks good. Now just update the compose compiler version per my answer  and everything should work fine. You can also update androidx-material3-adaptive-navigation-suite's version to "1.0.0-alpha07", this doesn't affect your problem, though.
